Purpose of Timestamp Assignment in UniswapV3's Observation Growth
When I studying UniswapV3's price oracle, I found that new observations are assigned a timestamp of 1 when observation.grow() is called. This assignment appears to indicate that the new observations have been added but not yet initialized. However, given that observation.initialized already serves to indicate initialization status, this assignment of a timestamp seems redundant.
Could you clarify the rationale behind setting the timestamp to 1? Is this practice intended to increase gas costs to prevent unnecessary grow() function calls?
Thank you.

Yes it's all related to gas costs. The code in the github repo has extra comments that explain it: https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/blob/main/contracts/libraries/Oracle.sol#L116-L117
        // store in each slot to prevent fresh SSTOREs in swaps
        // this data will not be used because the initialized boolean is still false

Basically they want to warmup the storage slot so that normal users later on don't have to pay extra gas.
